# Local notification to vibrate without sound

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification, iphone-vibrate

My goal is to have a local notification vibrate the phone without sound.

I have been googling around and am leaning towards using a sound file that is a blank (nothing to hear) sound. But I am curious if there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell vibrate and sound come hand in hand so your sugeestion of the blank sound file is probably the most effective to get the result you need.